# Hide Object In RDLC When Printing

Tags: vb.net, report, rdlc

I am developing a program with RDLC report in VB.NET. I just want to know that, is it possible to  view the entire report layout in preview then hide some objects during printing?
If yes, I need help on how to fix this problem.